# Servlet request processing

Tags: java, servlets

Greetings,

I have a servlet which pulls an "action" parameter from a querystring. Based on this string I perform the required action.

What is the best way to check the value of the "action" parameter. Currently my code is a long if, else if, else if, else if...when I'd rather have some kind of mapping from string to method where I didn't have so many branch conditions.

Regards,

Ken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Populate a `Map<String, Action>` where `String` represents the condition for which you would like to grab the action and `Action` is the interface which you've definied for your actions.

E.g.

```
Action action = actions.get(request.getMethod() + request.getPathInfo());
if (action != null) {
    action.execute(request, response);
}
```

You can find a detailed example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/3542297#3542297).

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to keep them in a file (XML file or Properties file).
Load them into the memory. It can be stored in some Map.
Based the key, the operation(value) can be decided.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a helper class with an enum type might help:

```
public class ActionHelper {
    public enum ServletAction {
         ActionEdit,
         ActionOpen,
         ActionDelete,
         ActionUndefined
    }

    public static ServletAction getAction(String action)
    {
         action = action != null ? action : "";
         if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")) 
             return ServletAction.ActionEdit;
         else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("open")) 
             return ServletAction.ActionOpen;
         else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) 
             return ServletAction.ActionDelete;
         return ServletAction.ActionUndefined;
    }
}
```

Then, your servlet will have something short and simple like:

```
ServletAction sa = ActionHelper.getAction(request.getParameter("action"));
switch (sa) {
    case ServletAction.ActionEdit:
        //
        break;
    // ... more cases
}
```